# Query is not being sorted properly

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I have this query I am using.  I need to sort it by `$variis`, but it seems the sort is not working. I double checked field names and tables.  All is correct but it won't sort it by the `$variis`:

Code:

```
//Unseen
$variis = "Need Help";
$myid = This is the user's id;

$sql = "select car_help.car_id, agent_names.agent_name, help_box.status, 
car_help.why_car, car_help.date_time_added, car_help.just_date, 
car_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from car_help LEFT JOIN agent_names on car_help.agent_whois = agent_names.agent_id 
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and car_help.system_id='$myid' 
and added_by <> '$myid' and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select magazine_help.note_id, agent_names.agent_name, help_box.status, 
magazine_help.note_name, magazine_help.date_time_added, 
magazine_help.just_date, magazine_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from magazine_help LEFT JOIN agent_names on 
magazine_help.agent_id = agent_names.agent_id 
where agent_names.system_id='$myid' and 
magazine_help.system_id = '$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select motorcycle_help.rand_id, agent_names.agent_name, 
help_box.status, motorcycle_help.rand_name, motorcycle_help.date_time_added,     
motorcycle_help.just_date, motorcycle_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from motorcycle_help LEFT JOIN agent_names ON 
motorcycle_help.by_who = agent_names.agent_id
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and 
motorcycle_help.system_id='$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select mobile_questions.bal_test_id, agent_names.agent_name, 
help_box.status, mobile_questions.bal_why, mobile_questions.date_time_added,   
mobile_questions.just_date, mobile_questions.type, agent_names.agent_id
from mobile_questions LEFT JOIN agent_names ON 
mobile_questions.agent_who_ordered = agent_names.agent_id
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and 
mobile_questions.system_id='$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
ORDER BY date_time_added DESC LIMIT $startrow, 20";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());


if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$row1 = $row['row_name'];


print("$row1");
}

}
```

Ok an update: I selected the `status` field and displayed it. For all of these rows that are being returned teh the status is `no help needed` when the `$variis` is in fact `need help`

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong...but you are ordering by "date_time_added". you are just using $variis to filter "help_box.status"

Comment: Does this query work at all, or is it just the "filter" that is not working?

Comment: @abdullahbattal yes everything is working except for the filter.

Comment: ok an update: i selected the 'status' field and displayed it.  For all of these rows that are being returned teh the status is "no help needed" when the $variis is in fact "need help".

Comment: So what is the problem? Wrong sorting of items in result or wrong results?

Answer (score 4):

Please read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize  the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from magazine_help LEFT JOIN agent_names on 
magazine_help.agent_id = agent_names.agent_id **and help_box.status = '$variis'**
where agent_names.system_id='$myid' and 
magazine_help.system_id = '$myid' and added_by <> '$myid'
```

instead of using the *and help_box.status = '$variis'* in the where clause, use it in the join

Comment: hey matias.  thanks but it still works the same way.  going crazy trying to find out the reason.  everything is working in the query except for this sort function.

Comment: the table "help_box"...where is it joined?

Answer (score 0):

I believe by "sort", you mean "filter".
You should include help_box table in your FROM clause every time you need `help_box.status` in your WHERE clause. Only then it can run.

Comment: No, he means 'sort by', which has a peculiarity in UNION queries, which dev-null's answer covers.

Comment: I still think he means "filter"... Please read the comments below the question between Matias and AAA, the questioner admits it too.