# php mysql union order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, union

I've gotten my union statement to work the way I want it, but I cant seem to get it to order the 2 tables without erroring out.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT userid_2 FROM messages 
WHERE userid_1='$dbid' UNION SELECT userid_1 FROM messages WHERE userid_2='$dbid'");
```

and I'm trying to incorporate `ORDER BY date` into it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the the error you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881587/query-is-not-being-sorted-properly/7881698#7881698

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/skycityc/public_html/pages/messages.php on line 141

Comment: That mean's there's a mysql_error Joe Jankowiak, try do: $q = mysql_query("etc") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: wow totally forgot about mysql_error(), realized i needed userid_1, date so it loads the date but then it doesnt keep it distinct.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
$query = mysql_query("
      SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT userid_2,date FROM messages 
         WHERE userid_1='$dbid' 
         UNION 
         SELECT userid_1, date
         FROM messages 
         WHERE userid_2='$dbid'
      ) as table1
 ORDER by table1.date");
```

**EDIT:**
based on your comment below I'll do something like that:

```
      SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT userid_1,userid_2 FROM messages 
         WHERE userid_1='$dbid' 
         ORDER BY date ASC) as table1
      UNION 
      SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT userid_1,userid_2
         FROM messages 
         WHERE userid_2='$dbid'
         ORDER BY date ASC) as table2
```

Comment: the only thing id have to change on this would be the field that im trying to sort it by? so table1.date? If so that doesn't work either. Same error.

Comment: yes, I edited the query, you need to select also the date from the "internal" query... otherwise you cant sort by date... try now... I tried in a sample table and it worked...

Comment: That ordered it but now its not being distinct. and you cant put DISTINCT in there can you because its supposed to already be it?

Comment: I don't get your problem the internal query return a table composed by some userid_2 and some userid_1, then you order it by date... maybe do you want to order by id and date?

Comment: Ill try to explain this but it probably wont make much sense.

what i have is a messaging system where it loads all ur recent conversations.
Userid_1 is the sender and Userid_2 is the receiver of the message
In the inbox it has to load all the messages that are sent to you along with the ones youve sent, but i need it to group it by the ID
Basically it needs to only show the first message of each conversation and it needs to be ordered by the date.

Comment: edited the post, try the new query... hope this help, I haven't test it...

Comment: I think you may have gotten it. Let me just do a bit more testing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have much to do with your problem, but you should not be using the mysql php extension anymore. It is planned for depreciation (see http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=131031747409271&w=2), you should consider switching to mysqli or PDO.